# Facing error while generating android apk in glide flutter_wechat_assets_picker

Tags: android, flutter, android-glide, flutter-build

Following the error that occurs while generating apk in flutter

I am using flutter_wechat_assets_picker library which uses the glide

> Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl is defined multiple times: /Users/akshaypatel/Documents/Wappnet/Fultter/Wappnet/vCreation/github/vCreations-Flutter/build/local_image_provider/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar:com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl.class, /Users/akshaypatel/Documents/Wappnet/Fultter/Wappnet/vCreation/github/vCreations-Flutter/build/app/intermediates/javac/release/classes/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl.class

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/akshaypatel/Documents/Wappnet/Fultter/Wappnet/vCreation/github/vCreations-Flutter/build/local_image_provider/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar:com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl.class

This are the steps I have followed to configure Glide in android

- implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0' kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

  in app/build.gradle file
- apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' in app/build.gradle file
- add ExampleAppGlideModule.java file in kotlin folder
  [Current pubspec.yaml configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjNFS.png)

[image: This is the error log that I have encounter]

Answer (score 0):

Following steps has resolved my issue

1. I have added (ExampleAppGlideModule) java file in kotlin folder i change it to kotlin file
2. I have removed local_image_provider library which is responsible for GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl is defined multiple times while generating the apk.